# Lighting and shading Orange juice

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Reference image:

[image: Reference image]
(larger versions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Orange_juice_1_edit1.jpg))

Attempt 1

Simple SSS shader:

[image: with simple SSS materal] [image]

setup:

[image: node setup for SSS mat]

Less simple SSS attempt:

[image] [image]

I also tried a absorption shader: (the absorption node group is from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tcHETob9eQ))

[image]

[image]

My main question is, how to get that lightening effect around the edges, as there is less juice between the light and the camera.. (and also make it more transparent/refractive)
like here: [image]

(and in general, make it look more like orange juice)

Thanks

Comment: time to read up on studio lighting, rim lighting..etc.http://bensimonds.com/2010/06/03/lighting-tips-from-the-masters/

Comment: it's the material setup that I want to know about 
@zeffii I'm pretty sure that the effect is more part of the material than the lighting (from looking at actual orange juice)

Comment: materials and lighting go hand in hand.

Comment: very true, however the bit I circled in the reference image looks to me more like it was scattered out than directory lit.

Comment: So I'm guessing it's lighter because the liquid is thinner there and so more light can be scattered through.. (I would think the same should be true {though to a lesser degree} of the surface of the orange juice if it was flat)

Comment: @gandalf3 Also, my personal recommendation is to avoid the glossy BSDF with liquids. The glass shader should handle reflections on its own well enough.

Comment: @Gwenn thats what I meant.. (thinner as in less liquid between the camera and a light source) I agree there should be some refraction somewhere (with the glass bsdf) but I can't figure out where to add it in. (it only looks transparent when it's really "thin")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SSS material is the one your going to want to use. The reference is showing light scatter. The issue your having is lighting. There's not enough light for that edge to show.

Here's what I got after a few minutes of experimenting:

[image: orange juice render]

I have a large light source has a strength of **10.0** and I have an environment map in the background. That's what gives it enough light to scatter.
Here's the scene setup:

[image: Scene setup]

Your shader looks OK, but if your interested, here's mine:

[image: Shader setup]

Comment: Thanks.. but what is the point of the second mix node?

Comment: @gandalf3 thanks for the heads up. I fixed it.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using both a glossy and a glass node? instead of just glass or glossy + refraction?

Comment: It just gives you a little more control. You could just use a glass shader, but I prefer this setup.

Comment: I mean, why not use a refraction shader instead of the glass? I suppose it doesn't make much difference in this case, but I was wondering if you had a reason..

Comment: @gandalf3, nope, not really. I just chose glass, because that's one I usually work with. I just wanted to put something out there. (I was mainly focusing on the lighting)

Comment: Side question: Why are the node connections straight? Mine are smoothed curves.

Comment: @ForestKa, it won't effect the outcome in any way. It's  just a setting you can change in the User Preferences. In the user preferences go Themes > Node Editor and set the Noodle Curve to 0.

Comment: I know it won't. I was just curious why they were straight. Thanks for answering that.

Comment: Hmm. thanks, I was wondering about that too ;)