# How can I create a milky, smooth, transluscent plastic material with nodes?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have been searching around for quite a while now. How to create a plastic material which absorbs light with properties of having a volume absorption node;is shiny on the surface (glossy) and is a nice milky white. Something of an eye candy as far as node materials are concerned.

I do not know if this question has been answered yet, so if it has please send me a link and I will check out the procedure. Thanks..!

Comment: Do a search for subsurface scatter.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/lighting-and-shading-orange-juice and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35731/1853

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some pictures of what kind of look you are going for.