# A lot of small pixels after rendering

Tags: rendering

Explain me please why do i have these very very small points (like pixels) after rendering. Is it connected with lightning and how to fix it?[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles). Also this could help with caustics: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24382/how-to-create-and-animate-the-water-reflection-caustics-on-an-object/ and this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/rendering-translucent-materals-through-glass-in-cycles and any other question about noise, fireflies, spots when render.

Comment: Those bright pixels are referred to as "fireflies". Read this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called fireflies and are caused by not enough samples.

I will refer you to the manual:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/optimizations/reducing_noise.html

> To understand where noise can come from, take for example this scene.
>   When we trace a light ray into the specified location, this is what
>   the diffuse shader “sees”. To find the light that is reflected from
>   this surface, we need to find the average color from all these pixels.
>   Note the glossy highlight on the sphere, and the bright spot the lamp
>   casts on the nearby wall. These hotspots are 100x brighter than other
>   parts of the image and will contribute significantly to the lighting
>   of this pixel...